# I am getting this exception when integrate quartz config xml and and spring in java

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I already created required qurtz table on database and mapped all bean reference of quartz xml correctly but still get exception.
my quartzconfig.xml contains:-

```
<bean name="scheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobFactory">
            <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="transactionManager" />
        </property>
        <property name="quartzProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">6000000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
                </prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">qrtz_</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">20000</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">Scheduler</prop> -->
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">SgsClusteredScheduler</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
        <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
        <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />
        <property name="triggers">

    <list>      

    <ref bean="companySaleUploaderJobTrigger" />

 </list>
</property>


    </bean>
```

**exception**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'scheduler' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/config/quartzConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store
>   trigger:
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext [See
>   nested exception: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:591)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) Caused
>   by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger:
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext [See
>   nested exception: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]

Comment: What is the quartz version you are using ?

Comment: http://quartz.10975.n7.nabble.com/Spring-amp-Quartz-Clustering-td9265.html

Comment: using  quartz_all_1.6.0.jar

Comment: @richakumari does the previous link help you , seems the problem with version of quartz .read here http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/41790-trouble-with-quartz-persistent-job

Comment: Thanks @san krish. There is version problem. now i am using spring 2.5 jar and quartz-all-1.5.0 jar then it works fine.

Comment: @richakumari welcome :) Post your answer and accept it . so that it will help others too

Answer (score 1):

Error occurs due to confliction of jars . now my problem is solve using two jar.

When i use **spring-3.1.2 release jar** with **quartz-all-1.8.6.jar** then my code work fine and now quartz trigger firing with oracle database.

**Quartzconfig.xml**

```
<bean name="scheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobFactory">
            <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="transactionManager" />
        </property>
        <property name="quartzProperties">          
                <props>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">6000000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>         
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
                </prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">qrtz_</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">20000</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">Scheduler</prop> -->
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">SgsClusteredScheduler</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true </prop>
            </props>

</property>
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
        <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
        <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />
        <property name="triggers">

    <list>      
    <ref bean="Emailschedule trigger" />

 </list>
</property>


    </bean>
```